# 'Unwrap' the text in select2

Tags: html, jquery-select2, multi-select

I have 5 multiselects(select2) placed in a single row. When I select more than 2 options from the dropdown in any of those selects, they expands downwards, which gives the page a weird look. Is it possible to somehow stop this expansion? Like somehow 'unwrap' the list of selected options?

I searched throughout the internet, but in all examples the select was as wide as the page, with only 2-3 options, hence no possibility of it expanding.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32787618/keeping-select2-element-a-fixed-size-with-scrolling

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keeping select2 element a fixed size with scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32787618/keeping-select2-element-a-fixed-size-with-scrolling)

Comment: Yup, it does. Thanks